# Collatz Conjecture in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

The [Collatz's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) states that any number can either be halved (if it is even) or multiplied by three and added one to (if it is odd) and eventually reach 1.

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to work out the series that a number takes to get to one and the amount of steps it takes.  The Python (3.x) code is:

```
i, k = 1, 1
fh=open("results.txt", "w")
print("Started")
def colapatz(x):
    seq = [x]
    j = 0
    while x > 1:
       if x % 2 == 0:
         x = x / 2
         j = j + 1
       else:
         x = 3 * x + 1
         j = j + 1
       seq.append(x)
    fh.write("Value number " + str(i) + " takes "+ str(j) + " steps.\n")
    fh.write("It takes the sequence: " + str(seq) + "\n")

#Call the function
while k<10000:
    k+=1
    i+=1
    colapatz(i)
print("Finished")
fh.close()
```

The is one of my first python programs that I've ever written, so any improvements would be great.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible improvement is to use recursion and memoization to implement a "dynamic programming" solution. This uses the results of previous calculations to speed up the process, as you will end up calculating the same sub-sequences repeatedly. For example:

```
def memo(f):
    def func(*args):
        if args not in func.cache: 
            func.cache[args] = f(*args)
        return func.cache[args]
    func.cache = {}
    return func

@memo
def collatz(n):
    if n == 1:
        count, seq = 0, []
    elif n % 2:
        count, seq = collatz(3 * n + 1)
    else:
        count, seq = collatz(n // 2)
    return count + 1, [n] + seq
```

*(Note the use of a decorator to implement the memoization.)*

Now, once you've run:

```
>>> collatz(10)
7, [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

then e.g. `collatz(8)` can just be looked up from the `cache`, so future calculations aren't needed:

```
>>> collatz.cache
{(1,): (1, [1]), (2,): (2, [2, 1]), (8,): (4, [8, 4, 2, 1]), 
 (4,): (3, [4, 2, 1]), (10,): (7, [10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]), 
 (5,): (6, [5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]), (16,): (5, [16, 8, 4, 2, 1])}
```

The downsides of this are:

1. It uses up a lot of space; and
2. As it's recursive, a long sequence can hit the recursion limit and crash the program.

Also, note that `count == len(seq)`, so you don't necessarily have to return (and store) both.

Answer (score 4):

## Style:

To get that out of the way: You don't follow the official python conventions. Please read the [PEP-8 Styleguide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and follow it.

## Approach:

As mentioned in [@jonrshape's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/66834/37660) you will most probably get a speedup if you cache the method's steps through this.

## Naming:

What does `colapatz` mean anyway?? also... `x, j, k, i` are not really descriptive names. Consider making them more speaking.

## Documentation:

If you were to "publish" this method as usable by the public I'd strongly suggest the use of [docstrings.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

```
def collatz(x):
   """returns number of collatz sequence steps.

   The collatz sequence is defined by perfoming mathematical operations 
   defined in the collatz conjecture on a positive number. 
   The conjecture states: If the current number is divisible by 2, divide it by 2,
   else multiply by 3 and add 1. If repeated sufficiently often, the end result is always 1.
   """
```